# Equal numbers in sub-array

Tags: code-golf, array

Given an array of numbers with `length >=3` and `length % 3 == 0`

`[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`

You will split it in sub-arrays of length 3

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, ...], [...`

And return an array with

- [0] => The amount of cases in the sub-array where **all numbers are equal**
- [1] => In case all numbers in sub-array are not equal, the amount of cases in the sub-array where **only 2 numbers are equal**

**Example and test cases:**

- Input: `[2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]` output `[1, 2]`

This is because

```
[[2, 4, 2], [5, 5, 5], [4, 2, 1], [3, 3, 1]]
  ^     ^    ^  ^  ^               ^  ^ 
   equal    all equal              equal
```

so 2 `equal` and 1 `all equal`

- `[3,5,6,5,5,7,6,6,8,7,7,7,3,4,2,4,4,3]     => [1, 3]`
- `[3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,5,4,3]           => [4, 0]`
- `[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]           => [0, 0]`

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes win.

---

PD: Apologies for my English.

Comment: The numbers in the test cases are all positive. Is that always the case?

Comment: @Dennis No. can be positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>60</s> <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```matlab
@(x)sum(sum(~diff(sort(reshape(x,3,[]))))'==[2 1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITvPsVexASW0vy1eoj4HiGHog16kEpbpSdfPW7SKoo7DLOH/ZjtjmPzaGOwRVHEA5v4cL@y5OfpEgIbun5kfTucm1vLJlToPKfZWOskCM9jYE6hwYpssKascEuZpFCjJGtUngPAGsDuwQkE5VeZU/kmyWRVWeZDzLNwGqFcOJ1va2ra5baFoTbxz5VvTuZ/5qa0idz/Tfxw9Kf08QU)

Saved 8 bytes thanks to Luis!

#### Explanation:

Reshapes the input into a matrix with 3 rows, and the appropriate amount of columns. It then sorts each of the columns, and calculates the difference between the elements on different rows. This gives a matrix with two rows, where identical numbers will have a zero, and different numbers will have a positive number. This is negated, so that all equal elements are `1`, and all unequal are `0`. We then sum each of those columns, giving us one of the three alternatives: `0 = All elements are unequal`, `1 = Two elements are equal` and `2 = All elements are equal`. We then check how many are `>1`, and how many are exactly `==1`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>9</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Dennis (use a new alias for `L€`, `Ẉ`)

```
Q3ÐƤẈċⱮ2
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Q@PCEY0se7uo40v1o4zqj////RxvrmOiY6pjpmOtY6FgCsTmQbQoUM9Yx0jGMBQA)**

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
3ôεÙg}12S¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f@PCWc1sPz0yvNTQKPrTo//9oYx1THTMgNtUxB9JmOhZAGgSNdUx0jIDYRMc4FgA)

**Explanation**

```
3ô          # split input into groups of 3
  ε  }      # for each triple
   Ù        # remove duplicates
    g       # and get the length
      12S¢  # count the number of 1s and 2s in the result
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

```javascript
f=([a,b,c,...d],t=p=0)=>1/a?f(d,t+!(a-b&&a-c?b-c||++p:b-c&&++p)):[t,p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BDoIwFET3ngI3TRs@BWwBJUEOQliUAkZDaCPEFXevbdWF0T@ZzCz@y9zEQyzyftVrNKt@MGascCOgAwmU0r6FtdJVQqpzGot6xD2s4R6LqENIRLLuIrltYahLWxCyhZCyWUG3Rqp5UdNAJ3XBI24YZJBbZ1DYzOFo04kBh4M1B9YSEsRx0KQQsHb3wzP/65R55V7Zh3yd4zkEyR@ee6awyye//mbtevrNJ443Tw)

#### How?

We recursively extract each triplet **[a,b,c]** from the input array and update two counters **t** (three-of-a-kind) and **p** (pair), using the following formula:

```javascript
t =
t + !(a - b && a - c ? b - c || ++p : b - c && ++p)
```

There are 5 possible cases which are detailed below, from 'all equal' to 'all distinct'.

```
a b c | a-b && a-c | b-c | b-c || ++p | b-c && ++p | t +=
------+------------+-----+------------+------------+------------
4 4 4 | false      | 0   | n/a        | 0          | !0    --> 1
4 4 5 | false      | ≠0  | n/a        | ++p        | !++p  --> 0
4 5 4 | false      | ≠0  | n/a        | ++p        | !++p  --> 0
5 4 4 | true       | 0   | ++p        | n/a        | !++p  --> 0
4 5 6 | true       | ≠0  | ≠0         | n/a        | !(≠0) --> 0
```

Comment: If output can have more than only `[0]` and `[1]` indexes _"Note: returns a 3-elements array with `[0]` and `[1]` returning th appropriate values, and `[2]` returning a dummy value (the number of 3-lists without any elements in common) . This is totally valid according to the current rules."_ https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166082/31257 62 bytes `a=>a.map(_=>++r[--new Set(a.slice(i,i+=3)).size],r=[i=0,i])&&r`

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
/Lml{kcQ3S2
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FLml%7BkcQ3S2&input=%5B3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C8%2C7%2C6%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
/Lml{kcQ3S2
      cQ3        Split the input into groups of 3.
  ml{k           Deduplicate and get the length of each.
/L               Count the number...
         S2      ... of 1s and 2s.
```

Comment: Fails for 3rd test (needs some all-equals AND some two-equal triples)

Answer (score 3):

## [oK](https://github.com/johnearnest/ok), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
+/(1 2=#=:)'0N3#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY09DoAgDIV3TtGEAYgxCi2gJFzBY7AweP8JSyXf8Nr3@tP3t4/RynZYD6HqWpw5H9SjGRuAIEAUZuUBGa@Q@yRuZk1wsU5QpohBhTJLwn8hCXGlJE7m3Vv2VzK/uPEB)

```
            0N3# /reshape into groups of 3 (see ngn's comment)
  (       )'     /for each group:
        =:       /    make a map from number -> indices
       #         /    count number of keys/values
   1 2=          /    check if the count is equal to 1 or 2 
+/               /sum together the columns
```

For [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), the 17 byte version is: `+/(1 2=#=:)'0N 3#`.

Comment: `0N 3` -> `0N3` (thanks to a parsing oddity in oK)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 70 bytes

```r
function(v,x=lengths(by(v,seq(0,a=v)%/%3,table)))c(sum(x<2),sum(x==2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBBTsQwDDyTV/iyii0ZAU3bBWnDJzgCh2zVLpVKCk12tQjx9uJYHODAjKxJ5LEnyrIOfh2OscvjHPHEZz/18ZBfEu4/5Jr6d7zm4E@0udo4zmE/9UTUYTq@4nlXEevB@4pozX3KCXaXMI0powHBBSg6dNxwK9XwVrTlW9FCxzVXUjU7YgN/UKacOgobZats/vXX6tnK/jvN@PFKxg2RGeYFA4wR9Kn0WRZ0IaN9tJznh7yM8YCB2D5btuDvQeR3a5Bm6T5FK1/z5q0l86XZZv0G)

***Previous versions :***

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 82 bytes

```r
function(v,a=!1:2){for(i in lengths(by(v,seq(0,a=v)%/%3,table)))a[i]=a[i]+1;a[-3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLTsMwEDzjr1gOlb1iK0idpOVhfoJjyMGNktZS5JTYVEJVvz2sLQ5wYEbrOcx41@t5GcwyfPouusmrM1lzWzxt8DJMs3LgPIy9P8RjUPsvdkP/oR44c8bV/UpTtPuxR0TbuNak4654ts1at9cl9iEGeFnD6EJUAhg3kNEpTRXVXBVtWWvasSZqKmnDVZJGEvAH6ZbOicQqs86s/s2XObPl/o95xk@WZxSIIm1o04b5qXhJDToblWwkxektzs4flEWSrSQJ5hVYflsDm8l995L/5WSkRHHNs8XyDQ)

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 93 bytes

```r
function(v,a=table(lengths(by(v,0:(length(v)-1)%/%3,unique)))[c('1','2')])`[<-`(a,is.na(a),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/LasMwEDxXX6FL0C6s0zh@pA1xf6JHNxDFyInAyK0lB0rpt7srkUN76AzLIO1oRzstfbP0s@uCHR3cSDdBnwcDg3GXcPVw/uTLzf5@hhtmOa4eVwXNzn7MBhHbDlSuSG0VHvHUHrITaLJ@7TRopA0uwfjg5SGTg/UBhGQ8yIQOCqqo5qpox1rTE2tkQSVtuUoqkIT8g/iqSI7IKrFOrP71l8mz4/nPKePu5YwcUfTjBFpaJ9NX8SsO6HQA1SoK42uYrLvEZdSR95TNi2T53eq5GbtvTpE3741SKL5Ttlh@AA)

Comment: Possibly porting the Octave answer will be more efficient, but `a=!1:2` is a bit shorter.

Comment: @Giuseppe: thanks, and saved other 5 bytes using `seq(0,a=v)` instead of `0:(length(v)-1)` ;) Unfortunately I don't know octave so I cannot read that answer easily...

Comment: @Giuseppe : changed approach and saved a lot of bytes :)

Comment: Great approach! I had something shorter by `apply`ing `unique` but it fails for the third test case. Your `by` approach is safer

Comment: @JayCe: fortunately R 3.2.0 introduced lengths function that saves a lot of bytes... but they should introduce a shorted lambda functions definition in R, in order to be more competitive in code golf :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 116 bytes

```java
l->{int r[]={0,0,0},i=0,a,b,c;for(;i<l.length;b=l[i++],c=l[i++],r[a==b?b==c?0:1:b==c|a==c?1:2]++)a=l[i++];return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFRT4MwEH7fr7gsWQLuJGOMqWBdfPHNpz0SHgrC7OyAtMeSZfLbZynMGDXX9nr9Pq7fR/f8yG/3bx8XcWhqRbA3tdeSkN5NPPlzVrZVTqKu/gU1qYIfeiiXXGt45aKC8wSgaTMpctDEyaRjLd7gYDBnS0pUuyQFrnbatVSAl/GKR1FRkqJdn6BkF3n7dDYVqCRl5wWa6FCwBXLMMI/LWjmxeJSeLKodvccZk4mYz1PMrxuVcMayTcZYvllEftRvPnlf@dEync9dPjJjVVCrKlBxd4mtJivC6KRCkwY2KgU4LxFWCGYNr2MofYTADr/DKzfAENdmhnhn8hrvTe4jwBUuzVxh8JMcWKCP0MbaRvibtrLQnen2YDuOFNPR7yyrGyyY/wOO9WFdRIMX99vKAKlCt5KMw9LjTSNPTs9y45GzPWkqDl7dkteYl6PSmc50BDM9q6YIz0rxk/aoHp51@PTv8XCFOzbtNXaT7vIF)

Note: returns a 3-elements array with `[0]` and `[1]` returning th appropriate values, and `[2]` returning a dummy value (the number of 3-lists without any elements in common) . This is totally valid according to the current rules.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 106 bytes

```powershell
param($a)for(;$a){$x,$y,$z,$a=$a;if($x-eq$y-and$y-eq$z){$i++}else{$j+=$x-eq$y-or$y-eq$z-or$z-eq$x}}+$i,+$j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCsIwFEQv8xcpmS601iql4FU@mGJKNDVdmKbk7PEXdDEzj@HN/mPC8jDOlTJz4KcirkYfVC@7UQStoATigbi3o6JYmzetNb/u0oJJLKt1Nm4xG016@Bs@/ISd0k4xZ00WmqZSyk01OKHFGR0uuEo64Va@Bkccqi8)

Exactly what it says on the tin. Loops over input `$a`. Each iteration, peels off `$x,$y,$z` as the next three elements. Tests `if` they're all equal and if so, increments `$i`. `Else`, increments `$j` if at least one pair is equal. Once the loop is complete, output `$i` and `$j` as integers.

*So ... many ... dollars ...*

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
2õ@ò3 x_â Ê¶X
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MvVA8jMgeF/iIMq2WA==&input=WzIsIDQsIDIsIDUsIDUsIDUsIDQsIDIsIDEsIDMsIDMsIDFdCi1R)

---

### Explanation

```
2õ                :Range [1,2]
  @               :Pass each X through a function
   ò3             :  Split input to arrays of length 3
       _          :  Pass each through a function
        â         :    Remove duplicates
          Ê       :    Get length
           ¶X     :    Test for equality with X
      x           :  Reduce by addition
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>77</s> <s>72</s> 65 bytes

```python
lambda a:map([len(set(t))for t in zip(*[iter(a)]*3)].count,(1,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7RCsIwDEWf9Sv6tlaC0HbddDB/pPah6oaFrSuzPujP17QKcgkJNzeHhFe8L16ksT@nyc6XmyW2m22geho8fQyRRsbGZSWROE/eLtCddnFYqWVmJ5nZX5enj0A5CMZSDtoc1FqCggZLQYu9gQP2LAk1CKwapAGCMVmsLFXUFKl/oC5mi4RjofyWSOEGtCi872meeAFyY7rtJqzOR2Kh6k8VjPhy@gA)

7 bytes saved via a clever trick from [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)

Comment: You can generate the list of triplets shorter as `zip(*[iter(a)]*3)`.

Comment: @xnor: Very nice; I wondered if there was a shorter way...

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 68 bytes

```
(.+)¶(.+)¶(.+)
;$1;$2;$3;$1;
%M`(;\d+)(?=\1;)
s`((1)|(3)|.)+
$#3 $#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZwQ46L9X0NPW/PQNgTJZa1iaK1iZK1iDGJwqfomaFjHpGhratjbxhhaa3IVJ2hoGGrWaBhr1uhpanOpKBsrqCgb/f9vpGOiY6RjCoYglqGOMRAachkD@WZgUXMgbaZjAaRB0BisygQIjbmMwWpNwBBighkYmkJlTcAi5kC9lmD9UBmQLQA) Link includes test cases with header to convert to desired format of one value per line. Explanation:

```
(.+)¶(.+)¶(.+)
;$1;$2;$3;$1;
```

Collect three values onto each line with separators and duplicate the first one at the end.

```
%M`(;\d+)(?=\1;)
```

Count the number of pairs of duplicates.

```
s`((1)|(3)|.)+
$#3 $#2
```

Count the number of `3`s and `1`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
íUÖ←#"ë╕
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a155991b232289b8&i=[3,5,6,5,5,7,6,6,8,7,7,7,3,4,2,4,4,3]%0A[3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,5,4,3]%0A[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>16</strike> 15 bytes

-1 byte thanks to cole!

```
1#.1 2=/_3#@=\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCoNADETv@xWDHkSQrWvWtQoL/ZCWHoqLePHg2W/fJrFFHiFhZpisOe3RosWENrvSOnTx9qbyEZ@vXJvCokrRVmhwTEi7MfNn2ZDQwfP0ilwOxLi/TSwHNQfeAXfeAmnYM4QrS6oLZ2FQpJiukFdj4KpR634B@Z2/)

Pretty much the same approach as the majority of solutions.

### Explanation:

```
        _3    \]  - split the input into sublists of lenght 3
          #@~.    - for each triplet remove duplicates and take the length 
   1 2=/          - compare with 1 and 2
1#.               - add up
```

Comment: `#@~.` -> `#@=`

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 113 bytes

```
(lambda(l &aux(a 0)(b 0))(loop for(x y z)on l by #'cdddr do(if(= x y z)(incf a)(if(/= x y z)()(incf b))))`(,a,b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9NCsJADIX3nuKhqAkI/kytutCzmHYoFGqn1BbURa9eM7E4D5LwJbxk8qp8NiNVITQoQouybvpOI9ZEByQ44GiK1R5OtecZOSWp8ZPmFGfNUc7mEpVjxDFnKOpnk5qONhD7ibGTGlzMZOrFZczwAaRHPaRDh/kgwPUGDDIs59OhpKfLI/NCFVbSv0iwY8o08P9P9MIbHw41KmRvLNa5975VcyoLuuLXpbLOCwhHtv3DCWes704b2Wg12mYF4xc)

Used the fact that in Common Lisp `(= x y z)` gives true if all the three elements are equal, and `(/= x y z)` gives true if no pair of numbers is equal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 23 bytes

```
S2,3,` 
%Cq`\S+
*\C`1
2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvp6p0aNuhbUp2Gu4J/4ONdIx1EhS4VJ0LE2KCtbm0YpwTDLmM/v83UjBRMFIwBUMQy1DBGAgNuYyBfDOwqDmQNlOwANIgaAxWZQKExlzGYLUmYAgxwQwMTaGyJmARc6BeS7B@qAzIFgA)

#### Explanation

```
S2,3,`
```

Split the input at every 3rd space starting at the (0-based) 2nd, i.e. split the input into groups of three.

```
%Cq`\S+
```

On each line (`%`) count the number (`C`) of unique (`q`) values (`\S+`).

```
*\C`1
```

Count the number of `1`s and print them with a trailing linefeed (`\`), but do so in a dry-run (`*`) so that we don't lose the previous result.

```
2
```

Count the number of `2`s (and print them automatically).

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

Saved two bytes thanks to Martin Ender.

```
{#~Count~{_},#~Count~{_,_}}&@BlockMap[Union,#,3]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsIwEIRfZSHQ04q06Y8elKJnwYunEEooFoM2FYmnkL56TLZC@Q6zzAyzo7KP@6is7lUY4ADBsfk8fY2dXedxvbHzPmtPr6l/XtRb3IyeDDLkMgvXjzZWMNgcYRBMSshg24JzBZZYYEWkK0ceyT2C49GqKWii1riLmuBULCN8qXGyEstOTVRroSSziQt7WvmH6Z334Qc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 90 bytes

```hs
g[]=[]
g(a:b:c:x)=(sum$map fromEnum[a==b,a==c,b==c]):g x
f x=[sum[1|y<-g x,y==n]|n<-[3,1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dUzBDoIwDL3zFT14wKQcxhgocUe/YtlhoCCRDQOSQMK/Y516MdrXvqbt67uY4Xpu23WtlZZKB3Vo8iIv82krw2G0G2tuUPWdPbrRKiNlgUQlFkR6m9cwBRVMUpFUsWU@RLTBWUqnF3eIFEem9WpN40DCqQuA4tY37g4bqEDFCAkCsfjka2QI3CfT3y8cBaZUAjPqKe6oP8ExwZgqQf7jh/v7E8Ij9RB/1IlXZOS99/5vJfkzvT4A)

Looks a bit awkward...

Answer (score 2):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 92 bytes

```
fn a->import Enum;c=map chunk(a,3),&(length uniq&1);{count(c,&(&1==1)),count(c,&(&1==2))}end
```

First, chunks the list into size length 3 `chunk(a,3)`

Secondly, it converts finds the length of each element, uniqified; `map chunk(a,3),&(length uniq&1)`.

Finally, it returns an array consisting of the number of times the resulting list is equal to one `count(c,&(&1==1))` and the number of times the resulting list is equal to two `count(c,&(&1==2))`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NCoJAFIX3PsXFhcyFSRitVYybaNGqB4iQYZx0SK82jhGYz25WtAg@DpwfOKa2D@vmUTnHIZ9Awq4tTGzuqs577yyV7HCMS@N7FoaIwbILnhmw@UKgVpltutZ52NPQbLVsVAe6GujKFE@RR6w2VPoKBrK3SOB21O1AnumliYSUApH/JwniZKiYMWb4vlmuLfWd0Z7hfEo4rDksuvnxtYJD@kGcXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```ruby
->a{[1,2].map{|x|a.each_slice(3).count{|y|x==y.uniq.size}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NCsIwEITvPoVHhRhItj96iC8SgsSQYkHbai00Jn32mKyCyHeYZWaYfUxnFxsRd0ftJSNc0ZsefJiDplaby2m8tsZuYEtNP3VPH1yYhXB06to7HduXXZYlDutGSk4KwkmJ5IsRSDClVhhDsisM66QV2SfNAJaLBPyqgHbms1ch5X@pwKBOSwdc@xbya6XiGw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```
ò3 ®â l
[Uè¥1 Uè¥2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AmY4VD6w4vUsjhig49vOLQUkMFMGUU@/9/tLEOCJqAoSkYmoGhKZBvHKugAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü┬─*HTÜ╫\Ä╢qm♥
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81c2c42a48549ad75c8eb6716d03&i=[2,+4,+2,+5,+5,+5,+4,+2,+1,+3,+3,+1]%0A[3,5,6,5,5,7,6,6,8,7,7,7,3,4,2,4,4,3]%0A[1,1,1]&m=2)

Comment: `[3,5,6,5,5,7,6,6,8,7,7,7,3,4,2,4,4,3]` outputs `[2,3]` instead `[1,3]`

Comment: `[3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,5,4,3]` outputs `[1,0]` instead `[4,0]`

Comment: `[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` outputs `[5,0]` instead `[0,0]`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz fixed

Comment: It doesn't currently show any output for `[1,1,1]`.  If you use `2(` instead of `1T` it will always trim/pad to exactly size 2.

Comment: @recursive fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 80 bytes

```
[A,B,C|T]-X/Y:-T-M/N,(A=B,B=C,X is M+1,Y=N;X=M,(A\=B,B\=C,Y=N;Y is N+1)).
_-0/0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU7LCoMwELz3K3KsuGu0MdoHoRjPevKgqPRUiiC1aMFL/z3dpD0WyjAs7Mzs7GOexumGyzoY02agIX9VPda8OWKFBS9hmykNWuVQs2FhhR9Bo8pTrQpSOit1pNlVY/XSjzwv2Fww5GFgzshaARISooSUZgJ7mhYCYtgRYxA9ZlwDW@fheR3vW/tGT0c@aeGcFtIhcZB/c7HzptR3cJ3fDHVGv3PmDQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `pair-rocket`, 58 bytes

```factor
[ 3 group 1 => 2 [ '[ cardinality _ = ] count ] with map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDBSgMxEL3vV7ybJwtttlu11Kt48SKelkVCTNuwNYmTWWQp/fZ1dlQQ80he8t5jwszeOk40vTw/Pj3c4UBpyCEeUDwX7GnEu@XjorDlUDi4AltKEgoJvafoT5L8GHx0viCTZx4zhcjINtA1Jdd7xraqzhVknbFCLXutmG9LGMESlx/fiN6ouxFucCM8w2i6Fpg/WaP6jO@KjWL9L1Wrs5Fat1rvN7HSfy/V1MpDGxdhdy96i6sWztJbiPYUeMQrdujg0iCddfgMfJS5ZHTTfMpwXL@YvgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Desmos, 84 bytes

```
l(r)=r.length
b=[l(k[3x-2...3x].unique)forx=[1...l(k)/3]]
f(k)=[l(b[b=1]),l(b[b=2])]
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gc3b94ydvy)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>61</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```arturo
$->a[b:[x,y,z]map[1,2]'n->enumerate a b->n=size tally@b]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?0DgOIE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
hmLkoLuC3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyPXJzvfp9TZ@P///9HGOqY6ZkBsqmMOpM10LIA0CBrrmOgYAbGJjnEsAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
3ẇƛ∪L;:1O$2Ox
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIz4bqHxpviiKpMOzoxTyQyT1csIiwiIiwiMSwxLDEsMiwzLDQsMSwxLDEsMiwyLDEiXQ==)

##### Explanation:

```
3ẇ             # 3-partition
  ƛ            # Open lambda map
   ∪L          # Length of sublist union
     ;         # Close lambda map
      :        # Duplicate for next operation
       1O      # Count 1
         $     # Swap
          2O   # Count 2
            x  # Print stack as list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), <s>108</s> 106 bytes

```hs
import List.Extra as E
m=List.map
f x=m(\j->E.count((==)j)<|m(List.length<<E.unique)<|E.groupsOf 3 x)[1,2]
```

[Try it on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/kR8yPsRw22Ha1)

Answer (score 1):

## C (GCC), <s>135</s> <s>128</s> 117 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

*-11 more, again thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

This is basically [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)'s answer now, since he's improved it by more than 13 percent.

```c
#define E(k)v[k-~i]==v[i
a;b;i;f(v,l)int*v;{for(a=b=i=0;i<l;i+=3)E()]&E(1)]?++a:E()]|E(1)]|E(1)+1]&&++b;*v=a;v[1]=b;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##VU/RTsMwDHzvV0RDVMniiZVuAy1EiId@RclDmiXIWkhhjCBRyq@XdEwq2LJPZ/nOslk8GTMMFzvrMFhS0T2L9X7xjUrKWGOmRSNQOBrBMwzHeRSdaw9Uy0aiXAq88wK5LFlFmcorWjB1z7nejvTrRE@dFyrPOW/EPEotYl0o2Yh@eNYYKMu6jJwjXSDRmloRSboS1rBJtYabhBu4TThmCSu4TrWCshf/pN6GJHzDT9u60Ydc/SH1Uk3b6SFrYBSwafhySCaOzh68J/b1XfstudwBOX60E30MMzi7/WKhkkM//AA)

Unfortunately, I'm too lazy to write a new explanation for the most recent answer, but it's quite similar to the previous 128-byte one:

```c
#define E(j,k)v[j+i]==v[k-~i]
a;b;i;f(v,l)int*v;{for(a=b=i=0;i<l;i+=3)E(,)&&E(,1)&&++a||(E(,)||E(,1)||E(1,1))&&++b;*v=a;v[1]=b;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##VY/RTsMgFIbv@xRkxgXWs7jabRqRCy/2FMgF7cCwIdU5MbGtr14P25Iq5PDl/If/J9Tzl7oehqutsS4YsqE72LMod7lTQkS5n/84lWleccctjeCZC8dZ5K1tDlSLSjix4O7Rc5eLkm0osOkUzwKR57rraJK67iQlFMjTrOKzKDSPslCi4v3wql2gLGszcln4DommlooI0pawgjXWCu6Qa7hHpl3CEm6xllD2/J/Vm4DGD/dtGptyyM2fRi7UeBu/ZWpIBjaKbwcMsXTy5D0x75/aP5DrLZDjVzO2z2ECl7QzC4UJ/fAL)

`f` takes a vector (`v`) and its length (`l`) as arguments, and return its values in the first two elements of that vector. Explanation:

```c
#define E(j,k)v[j+i]==v[k-~i] // k-~i == k-(-i-1) == k+i+1. an empty first argument equals +i, and an empty second argument equals -~i == i+1
a;b;i;
f(v,l)int*v;
{
    for(a=b=i=0;i<l;i+=3)
        E(,)&&E(,1)&&++a // if element i, i+1 and i+2 are all equal, increment a
        ||(E(,)||E(,1)||E(1,1))&&++b; // otherwise, if any two elements are equal, increment b
    *v=a; // set the first element in v to a
    v[1]=b; // set the second one to b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) +coreutils, 67 bytes

```zsh
for i j k;sort<<<"$i
$j
$k"|uniq -c>>a;h()grep -c "^ *$1" a;h 3;h 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LCsIwEEX3@YpLyKIVXKTpQ2kpfolQxD7RaqIbbb89TkaRw2Qm987j5XrfRvFbdOGxFzS@nS0GjJhKN9tHVVVSDUKNQk1yeV6HO7anum7KPoo7e77RD/KIjdISJMJQJH4tO6jDYt0qRIsEKUXGhErDEJocQ0rOekE5x45ywHBfShjuMqwEvltyJvv7KWsFze95x88Lt/wH)
<sub><s>[72b](https://tio.run/##PY3NDoIwEITvfYpJ0wOYeIDyowETn8RAjFAgEW31ovDsdbsa82V/MjPdvpzxXRS/RU/Nt4emmy0GjJgqN9tHXddSDUKNQk1yeV6HO7bnRpgo7u3lRjvkCRuVSFBStcJAVwapX6se6rhYtwrRIUVGlTNhS6CJhBxNSsF6SbPAjmZAcy4jNKc0K4HvlYLJ/37GWknv93zj54W//Ac)</s></sub>
<sub><s>[78b](https://tio.run/##PY3ZCsIwEEXf8xVDDMUKIul0UVqKXyKItE0f3JL6Ettvj5NR5DAL987inQn9On2LgZK9gg@2e3TnCdRqh03TSKWFyoRCObu7nebXbXzC9tK2PkmcGfsJUJh1OtAWySBPsFFagq8NIEUWlnoAdZytW4ToIYOcomBipwEJTQ6SUrJeUS1hTzWCPJcTyFPISuR7pWSKv5@zVtH@gW/8vPgrfAA)</s></sub>
<sub><s>[83b](https://tio.run/##PY3dCoJAEEbv9yk@bBEVInT8KQTpPaIgRF0v0nL1xvTZt3GLOOzOcr6Z2VkrU3v@WzR8DQ8E@dTpakRrhupZ3UfIy@5AV1Sl6uHIUMhISHIW3Q/jMnXtC/uyKGbX1aqtR5BQnt/wKGs4NwQydDALBcoVIrPmDeR5GfQqRI0IMZ/Esr1CEBNyQmxS6zOuKY5cN8j2xQzZLrJm47sltST/PLYu4/mT3fHLtr/MBw)</s></sub>
<sub><s>[102b](https://tio.run/##PY3NDoIwEITvfYoJNoSfGAOLoCEhvofRxBCgPSjawgX12XGpxnxpdzuzO52smtsgfIqOL3NFVI432wzQs2nuzWWAPK42dEJTqx6eTIRMhSSvksc41ifft0q3A0i0vYFGEIW2N7ykX@NNP7Cuq2oSKgg7TuMXvDMimXhgEVQqpPO77CAPL2PfQrRIkfHZOpYuATEJO8RK7vSCa44d1wVycxlDboqcsvBNyR3bv585reD9vcv4ectf8wc)</s></sub>
<sub><s>[116b](https://tio.run/##PU3LDoIwELz3KybaENAQA8tDY8KPqAeDVHoQtIUL4rfjUh@ZbHYyMzs72HpSfvAU5oaV6BtbddCTqe7VuYM8yOWGTqjKusVCRkLGQtKikIf1Wp88z9ZadSChWgMNfxXY1vCVHvtGPxCWY9l3CC9HIFR5UQzCv3IzGyAM@x@PMQSjsdNLKOYJT@ows4iThIgdYiVzes47w5b3DHK5hEEuRU6Z8WnJHNK/nzgt5/ud6/h686/pDQ)</s></sub>
<sub><s>[128b](https://tio.run/##PU3LDoJAELvzFU3cA2sCBoeHhoT4H8gJQfYg6AIXHt@Os@sjzWSattOZ@marXTk7@oH9VncaCu4c@L7Ixe5AxSpnI7ZwAxxBsiqbDuKSt0WWCZX2jaoH0Op8L/cy7Ts9QKhlbNULXrmU4wDvdgW8OsmyyXHvunqyAcKU/vgRk1x0v3ER85AnsjAs4CQhYIdYia2e8I5x4m1ANhcyyKbIKgafltgi@vuh1RK@P9uOr2d@bW8)</s></sub>

`for...` passes the args in groups of 3, `uniq` finds the doubles and triples, `grep` counts the results.

#### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) builtins only, 67 bytes

```
repeat $#/3 a+=(${#@[1,3]:#$1})&&shift 3;h()<<<${(M)#a:#$1};h 0;h 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1LCsIwEIb3PcVAQklQ0Dh9qGmhF/AE4iKLtulO2q6sOXucjCIf8@D/5/FafByU3rIxJdfGuX/2bgUpDghu1yq5ie5u9vi4CmmCzvPFT8MKaL3STdPITd20cGxaD0cKE4MdQXbveQlZNsAJCoqSSZ0BJAw5SErFek21gjPVBPJcQSBPISuJ75WKKf9@wVpN@xe@8fPSr/gB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 9 bytes

```
.,2,`?.`/3@,`$$@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWG_R0jHQS7PUS9I0ddBJUVBwgwlDZm5rRStHGOqY6ZkBsqmMOpM10LIA0CBrrmAD1mgChcaxSLFQHAA)

### Explanation

```
.    Map
,2    [1,2]
,     length of
`?     find indices in
.       map
`/ 3     split into chunks of 3
@         input
,        length of
`$        deduplicate
$          the chunk
@       of the number (1 or 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 30 bytes

```
(+«*.rotor(3)».Set).Bag{1,2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfQ/vQai29ovyS/CINY81Du/WCU0s09ZwS06sNdYxq/1srFCdWKiipxCvY2ilUpymoxNcqKaTlFynYGCmYKBgpmIIhiGWoYAyEhnY6CjbGQCEzsIQ5kDZTsADSIGgMVmgChMYQZcZgIRCEmGMGhqYIBSZgQXOgCZZgU6CSIOvs/gMA)

- `*.rotor(3)` breaks up the input list into groups of three elements.
- `».Set` converts each of those groups into a `Set`.
- `+«` converts each of those sets into its size.
- `.Bag` makes a `Bag` (a set with multiplicity) out of those sizes.
- `{1, 2}` looks up in that `Bag` the number of times sets with sizes of 1 and 2 were present.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

```
0&@@@c@BlockMap[Max@*c,#,3]/@{3,2}&
c=Counts
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsIwEETv@Y1CD7KiTZpWD5VFzwXBY@khBEuLthWNIJT012OyFeQdZpkZZntl2muvTKeVawq3jRFR4/E@6lupHlWpPrjSEIGoNzgJ4DZmujiN78G83PnZDaaK1ocGozqeL1oN88QmDilwkES4EhCexALzAxIyCnKvGey8BgQVU49YaoKswLKTEfJfSMnM/cKeVn5heGeZdV8)

```
            BlockMap[Max@*Counts,#,3]           #equal in each block of 3            
     Counts@                         /@{3,2}    count 3 equal, 2 equal
0&@@@                                           coerce Missing[...] to 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
3ẇıUl;12dc
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTMlRTElQkElODclQzQlQjFVbCUzQjEyZGMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUIyJTJDJTIwNCUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjA1JTJDJTIwNSUyQyUyMDUlMkMlMjA0JTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDElMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwMyUyQyUyMDElNUQmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
3ẇıUl;12dc  # Implicit input
3ẇ          # Split into threes
  ı  ;      # Map over the list:
   Ul       #  Length of uniquified list
      12dc  # Count 1s and 2s
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 111 bytes

```
proc S {L a\ 0 e\ 0} {lmap {x y z} $L {expr {$x-$y|$y-$z?$x==$y|$y==$z|$x==$z?[incr e]:0:[incr a]}}
list $a $e}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LCoNADLz7FUPZq6Cuj1YQf8CbR@tBxINgW1ELuut@@zbGtkyS2UyyA1nawdpxerUooQs0d3joqBjo4dGM0Cs2KANRQHfrOEGL1RXbLjZXqFysWcYNkdq5U3nVP9sJXZ166flsamOcoZ8XiAaiM5adydDRARACVKNfnK0PSA7fOFqSHlNGSIhjXIkPSFoOKENI3pKsHIgYMSP6z0PWEvp/Y4/vjDx8A8Chm8f3MuNCx6aoSjq6vhj7AQ)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 112 bytes

```
proc S {L a\ 0 e\ 0} {lmap {x y z} $L {expr {$x-$y||$y-$z?$x==$y|$y==$z|$x==$z?[incr e]:0:[incr a]}}
list $a $e}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LCoNADLz7FUPJVVDXRyuIP@DNo/Ug4kGwragFdd1vtzG2ZZLMZpIdyFR3@94Prxo5dIbqDgcNFwPdPaoeesaC1YAy6GbuB2iabVq2jRab1pTmJOGOFqZ1k25Ni/ZZD2jK2InPZ1UaY3XtOIEqUGN2sWZHS3uAD3ANfnG2LqAkXGNpxXrIGSBiDnFlPqB42eP0oWRLiXIgEISC4D/3RYv4/008vjP2cA0Ai4/u39OIC18bo8j56vJi9g8)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 114 bytes

```
proc S {L a\ 0 e\ 0} {lmap {x y z} $L {expr {$x==$y&&$y==$z?[incr a]:$x==$y|$y==$z|$x==$z?[incr e]:0}}
list $a $e}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LCoNADLz7FUNZPKvroxWkP@DNo/WwyB4E24paUNf9dhtjLZMHmUkGMtbttnX9u0YBk0M94EFTsTDtU3UwE2YsFiKH0VPXw4gpy8TsumKmvtzL5lX3UFV68OtBrzydqq5Sz1qnbYYRQkFou7E5eTomAEKAanTGMfqA5PCtYyTxMWWEhHqMK/UdkpYDyhCStyQzOyJGzIj@eshcQvc39vhp5OFbAA693X3GARf6N0VZ0N/VxW5f)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 108 bytes

```cs
x=>new[]{1,2}.Select(n=>x.Select((v,i)=>(v,g:i/3)).GroupBy(y=>y.g,y=>y.v).Count(y=>y.Distinct().Count()==n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU9Na4QwFLz7K3JM4FXX9WPb7ibQb3pbaG/iwUrcCttYYrQr4m@3z6xLiwyPSYY3b5i8vsrrcnxuVL57fVLNl9TZx1HuSmUELAVBCsLHExdK/iRp78N6cN/kUeaGKi5OlzdtoWRcIB1uSy9gzH3RVfN939GOi849gKWWuQ9Vo8xZfCxrUyo0X1TGuWJs3DoOJidpkhIja1MTTjCczJrTO@Tv3wcQQYwTwQY5hmvkCQGEsMYJIRiAeB5JfCBBuvAGdm9CZBFbRP9cIZDV0hXazQ1m3di82YF5/uxaWdeATYpKyyz/JLTNtK2DV861mG2y13iVFnSSmPte3WmddZSxrTOMvw)

Less golfed...

```cs
// x is the input list of ints
x=>x
  // 1 distinct number means 3/3 are the same
  // 2 distinct number means 2/3 are the same
  new[]{1,2}
  // iterate over the outer array to get an index
  .Select(n=>x
    // iterate over the whole list with an index
    // and break into groups of size 3
    .Select((v,i)=>v,g:i/3))
    .GroupBy(y=>y.g,y=>y.v)
     // count the distinct values in each group
     // and get the result based on outer array value
    .Count(y=>y.Distinct().Count()==n))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 98 bytes

```
proc A l {set 1 0;set 2 0
foreach a\ b\ c $l {incr [llength [lsort -u "$a $b $c"]]}
return $1\ $2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LDoMgELz7FRPDtYmCaJue/A71gIRWE6oG8UT8drvSR2Y3A7PD7uK1PY7FzRo1LMJqPHJk95M5suQxO6P0ANWib6HByDNO2qGx1kxPP9BhnZ3HZUPKFFgPptOu2xNn/OYmsLwF4/thX2qBHVdvEJLAgQI0APIXn2sOiBj5ngRBekkpURGXuBKfEGTmlAVEdImonJARZYT814uoVfT@Fnt8a9SDpuwIy@ZXNDX97VyPVj/e)

using `-unique` option of `lsort` command. I named `1` and `2` my variables for convenience, tough it seems pretty unusual to code `set 1 0` :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 12 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.88 bytes

```
3ApeZULE12dc
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrjB0LUqNCfVwNjVKSIUJQmQU3VaKNdBRMdBSApCkMQbiGOgrGYGQYC1EMAA)

Port of [Emigna's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165972/114446).

##### Explanation

```python
3ApeZULE12dc  # Implicit input
3Ap           # Split into sublists of length 3
   e   E      # For each sublist:
    ZU        #   Remove duplicates
      L       #   And get the length
        12dc  # Count the number of 1s and 2s in this list
              # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 14 bytes

```
_N#*UQ*g<>3M12
```

Takes the numbers as command-line arguments. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhbr4v2UtUIDtdJt7Ix9DY0gglC5ndFGOiY6RjqmYAhiGeoYA6EhTDMA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
_N#*UQ*g<>3M12
       g        ; List of command-line args
        <>3     ; Group into 3-element sublists
    UQ*         ; Uniquify each
  #*            ; Get length of each
_N              ; Lambda expression: how many times does the argument appear in ^
           M12  ; Map that lambda to the arguments 1 and 2
```

This returns a list containing the number of length-1 uniquified sublists and the number of length-2 uniquified sublists.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 89 bytes

```
!x=(~=sum;a=length(x);b=[x[i:i+2] for i=1:3:a];c=~allequal.(b);[c,a÷3-c-~allunique.(b)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBNTsMwEIX3OcU06sIWE9TUSVoSmRVHYIMsL5yfgpEJbRNLWeUibLrpGTgAp-AuLHDclkr4aTSy_T496X0cX63R6nA42n4Trb-fZgMnI-_sW6G4adrn_oUMtCi5GITO9c1SwuZ9D5rHOcuVLCo-KmOanVXmlpS0EBWqr08WVdH0blu9s830Iek54KfmD7rqSQDuCIYpZm5SXLmd4drtSQwTXLpJkMnJCPweRIzAJF5A5k2TUq_MK70i8AcmCIsrmHjzymXd-bwz5PLi_-DiBNIgENu9bnvTkvCx6XrYqq5r6hxChJkCzqFECIHAOHc3mJOZokBD6rsiCksKuoVanjq4lP0L)

Julia has `allequal` and `allunique` built in. To find the number of triplets containing exactly 2 matching values (all remaining cases), I subtract these two amounts from the total. Replacing `÷` with `/` saves one byte, but the value becomes a float.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 105 bytes

```
import sequtils
proc e[S](s:S):S=[1,2].mapIt s.distribute(s.len div 3).mapIt(it.deduplicate.len).count it
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDLCsIwEEX3fkWWDcRAm74sCG5dd1m6qG3Egb5sJv6Mm0Lxo_wbk1QFkbOYwD25GXJfeujm-aHxvE2fAN04TEiUvGqEVm3GaaiJLPLSU1lOs3xf-CwoeVeNR2PxBhROcNIoPcVb2ZMGbkTQNfcAeSMbPbZQVyhtTnk96B4J4PvBRdaXgUjvUAQsZAGLHPbkM2HwS7r5KsJEsRMSM2OWmmkR7kJoEL-6cJFl7Y0d0b8YujAxjTvX-pbsGiVdV_380Qs)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 82 bytes

Without recursion

```
a=>(b=[,0,0],a.map(d=>([x,y,z,...a]=a,x&&++b[new Set([x,y,z]).size])),[b[1],b[2]])
```

Try it:

```js
f=a=>(b=[,0,0],a.map(d=>([x,y,z,...a]=a,x&&++b[new Set([x,y,z]).size])),[b[1],b[2]])

console.log(f([3,5,6,5,5,7,6,6,8,7,7,7,3,4,2,4,4,3])); // [1, 3]
console.log(f([3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,5,4,3])); // [4, 0]
console.log(f([3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])); // [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 81 bytes

```powershell
for($r=@{};$i-$args.Count;$i++){$r[($args[$i++..++$i]|sort|gu).Count]++}
$r[1..2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/T8tv0hDpcjWobrWWiVTVyWxKL1Yzzm/NK8EyNXW1qxWKYrWAItGg/h6etraKpmxNcX5RSU16aWaEKWx2tq1XECFhnp6RrH/a7m4VEoUbBUcNEx0THRMddBJEA2ChjpGOsaaXFxqKmkKDiX//wMA)

### Explanations

Look at the array by taking sub arrays of three successive elements `$args[$i..($i+2)]`

We count the number of items in the sub array after sorting and removing duplicates (`gu`)

Then we increment the count in the result object `$r`

From `$r`, we then show only the entries with a single or two numbers

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 185 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLbsMgELz7K1aRIoHiWnGcRxuHSL1U6qGnqqcqB@zaCRHBFpBUkeNvdzGEPhQVj2FYZpf1elVOOe3Yoa6khj090eioGY8epaRnFdzYy6PINatE9HQlQVBl@yLX8EKZgCYA@ChKOJgNonKrlmAjvb9qycR2g5fwJpgGAk13ohzKpTt@FnpD1r84J2toTlSCJNaKxqF5cNqbGBnblYZZmBv@uWO8QGzFI16Ird7hJiMcMZzm/TKKcUotmeBUIlYiSkiGG0MyQnI8hoKrAuLWrVfz5UL7w9gZJ3hE4pSNSNKmsu3AjD57XSitzLe4DAOww20mIUxDMPPMw23jEBKLGId/HBIrmnv1wnKDe8sdEh9lapHchki8yOH78rnH7D/Pqdct7J0P/uYfH5c/to5uLisJqC8CrO5cMbDtAF8fWagj7392GdG65merxVdBbRpCl2gwND0yVEMxCF0yKtKV6xYnvzW7sNgFaoP@bbsv)

```scala
val f:Array[Int]=>Array[Int]=l=> {var r=Array(0,0,0);var i=0;var a,b,c=0;while(i<l.length){b=l(i);c=l(i+1);a=l(i+2);r(if(a==b){if(b==c)0 else 1} else if(b==c||a==c)1 else 2)+=1;i+=3};r}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJda8IwFH3vrzgIQoNdsdaPTXSwl8Ee9jT2NHxIu1YjsZUkOmT6212TNG1FBoc059xz7y03V6aU0@uV7falUNjSIw0PivHwRQh6kt6dnh@KVLGyCF/ri@eVyTZLFd4pK/DrAd9Zjl1FfCrWcg5T6etDCVasV2SOz4IpLI0TOFKO3HneCrXC8vmGgWvFmrVdQFSicfjDABqkE2RVcNjhNEASIO2oPxvGM/gMC/CQZ8VabUhTH0h0S5@RRkitgAGiVqSNOGpF4bMcfhVaIumWBLSeaD0lGCLjMkPUhC9WaD04n0Frd2SDI4LBspPDNI1reqm/wmuZnqvKpJLNsGqTJaMA4wDVOXGwNAoQG0QkuEmIjWnq3DNzr/Bo7haxqzI2iO9LxM5k0TSfOkz@yxw738z0fHKd2xz7//Y17JmXAr4eAhYPdhiks0gcIpMHrlcxD@l@z0/G655zX62ryv1ev9rgvuwXvcD@jAxVaXfZ2u9lW5aQ5jUu3uV6/QM)

```scala
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.function.Function

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f: Array[Int] => Array[Int] = l => {
      var r = Array(0, 0, 0)
      var i = 0
      var a, b, c = 0
      while (i < l.length) {
        b = l(i)
        c = l(i + 1)
        a = l(i + 2)
        r(if (a == b) {
          if (b == c) 0 else 1
        } else if (b == c || a == c) 1 else 2) += 1
        i += 3
      }
      r
    }
    val tests = Array(
      Array(2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1),
      Array(3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3),
      Array(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3),
      Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
    )
    for (test <- tests) {
      val result = f.apply(test)
      printf("%s: %s%n", Arrays.toString(test), Arrays.toString(result))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 57 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.125 bytes

```
3ẇƛUL12f=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJzPSIsIiIsIjPhuofGm1VMMTJmPSIsIiIsIlszLDMsMyw0LDQsNCw1LDUsNSw2LDYsNiw1LDQsM10iXQ==)

### Explained

```
3ẇƛUL12f=­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
3ẇ         # ‎⁡Wrap into chunks of 3
  ƛ        # ‎⁢to each chunk
   UL      # ‎⁣  take the length of the chunk uniquified
     12f=  # ‎⁤  and push whether 1 and 2 is in that length list
# ‎⁢⁡the s flag reduces the list by addition, which is performed element-wise vectorised
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).